# How can I extract all the ‘pdf’ files embedded in word document and save them in to a folder?

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have a word document which has 64 embedded pdf files. Is there any easy way to extract all these files to a folder without extracting each of the file manually?

Comment: Yes, do you want to do it from within Word (eg using VBA or VSTO), or outside (is it a docx?  what language do you prefer to work in?)

Comment: It is a docx. Any language is fine!

Comment: I've added a solution for Mac to do so:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157886/how-to-extract-embedded-pdf-from-word-document-in-linux-mac/64157887#64157887

Comment: Please check my solution in VBA below

Answer (score 1):

With docx4j, try something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentInputStream;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.OleObjectBinaryPart;

public class OLEExtractEmbeddedPDF {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/yourdocx.docx"));

    for (Map.Entry<PartName,Part> entry : wordMLPackage.getParts().getParts().entrySet()) {

        Part p = entry.getValue();
        if (p instanceof OleObjectBinaryPart) {

            OleObjectBinaryPart olePart = (OleObjectBinaryPart)p;
            DocumentInputStream inputStream = olePart.getFs().createDocumentInputStream("CONTENTS");
            byte[] pdfBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            // Do something with it here...
            System.out.println("Found " + p.getPartName().getName() );
        }           

    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy....rename .docx to .zip, extract zip, open zip....they're all there.

Comment: Why bother renaming? Most archivers will happily open archives regardless of filename extension.

Comment: it's not "all there", since for example, PDF files are binary files like oleObject1.bin and you can't open them by simply renaming the file to .pdf .

Answer (score 0):

Please find a solution here (**go to the info below**) - how to extract all the ‘pdf’ files embedded in word document and save them in to a folder:
Docx file is a zipped folder, **but it's not enough**, since the embedded files are binary files.

So here's how to do so:
[How to extract embedded PDF from WORD document in Linux (Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157886/how-to-extract-embedded-pdf-from-word-document-in-linux-mac/64157887#64157887)